# [HELP]Why Trees Leaves shadow from spotlight are not receiving light correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine

Please help me resolve this issue! Here how it's looks like:

https://youtu.be/3QOIyGFTt50

Tree leaves are not getting light dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your spot light is not being treated as a pixel light.

Go to **Edit -> Project Settings -> Quality** and make sure **Pixel Light Count** is 1 or more in the current Quality Level.

You may also set your light as "Important" in the inspector.